# Printing lists with brackets in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

This question is different from others because I am trying to print lists that have round brackets, not the square ones.

For example; I have this list:

```
list_of_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When you print out the list, you get this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want the printed version to look something like this:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: `tuple(list_of_numbers)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print(tuple(list_of_numbers))
```

or

```
print('(%s)' % ', '.join([str(i) for i in list_of_numbers]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_of_number_strings = [str(number) for number in list_of_numbers]
list_string = "({})".format(", ".join(list_of_number_strings))
print(list_string)
```

Should do the trick

The list_of_number_strings uses a simple list comprehension create a list of strings by casting every element in list_of_numbers to a string. 
Then we use simple string formatting and a join to create the string we want to print.

Comment: You can only join a list of strings

Answer (score 0):

tuple will print the round brackets

```
print(tuple(list_of_numbers))
```